How can I upload a PDF file to an external service with an HTTP callout?
We have a REST API that accepts PDF files and will analyze them and give insight about the PDF. I have added an Action Button if the user presses that button it will take all the PDF attachments and it will upload them to the external API and whatever response it gets is stored in a custom field called Attachment_Insight__c.
I have created an HTTP callout to the API but I am not sure how to upload the PDFs, I am trying to get the attachment from ContentDocument but not sure how can I get the PDFs.

Are your PDF's guaranteed to be small? Governor limits such as the 6M heap limit get in the way of large files.

You don't. Apex is not meant to send files over. If you need to upload files from Salesforce to an external system, let the user's browser do that or use a middleware service instead.
This middleware service could be a simple virtual private server (VPS) running in a public cloud environment such as Heroku. Then all you have to do is program that application to receive a request from Salesforce telling it which file to download and where to send it over to.
This is not to say that uploading files is not possible. It just isn't worth the hassle of doing it in Apex (from the development and maintenance perspective).
Most repositories containing public code on the theme show snippets/components that actually use the client side (the user's browser) to upload the files. Hopefully this gives you an idea of how bad of an idea handling file uploads in Apex is. For your use case - given that you mentioned that you use a quick action - I believe this is a suitable alternative. Have a component do the file upload (in JavaScript) instead of the platform's back end (in Apex).
For reference, take a look at the "working with presigned urls" from the AWS documentation or the "signed urls" documentation from GCP. I believe other cloud platforms and services might have similar features if you look for similar keywords (such as "presigned url").
